# Count rows in unix file excluding multiple headers and trailer

Tags: unix

My file has multiple headers/trailers. I need to find row count excluding the headers/trailers.

**Sample File is like:**

02**H1**

01**H2**

**0002**Rec1

**0002**Rec2

00**H2**

**0003**Rec1

**0003**Rec2

**0003**Rec3

T1

T2

**Expected Output**:

Count of all detail record = 5  (i.e substr($0,2,2) <> H1,H2 and substr($0,0,2) <> T1,T2 )

Count of 0002 = 2

Count of 0003 = 3

Answer (score 1):

Count of all detail record :

awk ' substr($0,2,2)!="H1" && substr($0,2,2)!="H2" && substr($0,0,2)!="T1" && substr($0,0,2)!="T2"' FILENAME | wc -l

Count of 0002:

awk ' substr($0,0,4)!="0002"' FILENAME | wc -l

Count of 0003:

awk ' substr($0,0,4)!="0003"' FILENAME | wc -l